# Is this PHP login part safe?

Tags: php, authentication

I´m just trying to learn something of php and I have two questions.
I want to make user roles based system, for the begining I just simply added a role for each user (admin, user, etc.), which is saved directly in users table in mysql? I mean my user table has columns id, nick, password, role. Is this OK, or even safe?

Second question is if it is safe to check user permisions like

```html
// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
// Check if the user has admin role, if not then load up page which tells u - You dont have perm to use this site
elseif($_SESSION["role"] !== "admin"){
    include "noperm.php";
    exit;
}
```

Can I do this, or there's still possibility that role user, or ununregistered user can access this page (e.c. user management site)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, for example when a user login in a php website, the username and password or whatever credential who him use will be sended open, or encrypted in a websites with md5 sha-2 and other algorithms, in short answer if the algorithm( encryption ) is weak the decryption will be easy for a attacker, and the user will be hacked, and is much more big the risk when is a connection with HTTP protocol, because HTTP is completely open compared to HTTPS, because HTTPS use a certificate with the client and the website, and all information is sended with a double encryption, encryption1 the algorithm of the php, encryption2 the certificate SSL, but includes the SSL Certificate can be spoofed if a organization produce a certificate similar with the same domain of the website attacked.

NOTE: The reallity is, It depend of how much the person secure the web site, and how much strong make the client the password...

CREATE YOU OWN ALGORITHM:

```
<?php
    // ENCRYPTION //
    $passwordOfTheUSER = "JonnyDeep74";
    $encryptedPassword = str_replace('o', 'UXK', $passwordOfTheUSER);
    $encryptedPassword = str_replace('a', 'PEA', $encryptedPassword);
    $encryptedPassword = str_replace('e', 'MIC', $encryptedPassword);
    echo "encrypted: $encryptedPassword, ";

    // DECRYPTION //
    $decryptedPassword = str_replace('UXK', 'o', $encryptedPassword);
    $decryptedPassword = str_replace('PEA', 'a', $decryptedPassword);
    $decryptedPassword = str_replace('MIC', 'e', $decryptedPassword);
    echo "decrypted: $decryptedPassword.";
?>
```

Comment: I can't rely on users, that they will have strong passwords - we know users. So how should I check if the user has or has not access to specific page?

It might be stupid question, but I´m still learning and in safty side of php I'm realy on the start.

Comment: I suggest force the users to make a strong password minimun 8 characters using a with $password = "SOMEPASS".length, using php, option 2 using a interval control or timer, if the user introduces the password more than 5 times, the interval will be activated preventing the introduce of more codes, and preventing someone can find the password.

Comment: Option 3, you can create your own algorithm, using the method str_replace(), if the user introduces a letter "a" the a will be replaced with a hard code like "546Dsa83cj" in the time to be sended, in the entry, and the ouput conversion will be "546Dsa83cj" = "a", remember with more big are the encryption who you make, more storage will be needed in your website...

Comment: I'm already edit my answer, and i add the method who you can create algorithms so easy, for prevent a credentials hacking... i hope be useful...